# javafx : ui toggling for buton clicks

Tags: user-interface, button, javafx, jfoenix

I have some button (JFoenix buttons) in my JavaFX program which is in left column below :
[image]

I want to look them like clicked once they are clicked and toggle if others are clicked. How do I do this?

Comment: I don't use JFoenix, but presumably it has a version of a [`ToggleButton`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html)?

Comment: JFoenix ToggleButton is very different from JavaFX ToggleButton. However I have already implemented those as regular JFoenix button, seems that I have to change that to JavaFx ToggleButton. It might be very unpleasant as I have to set styling for those buttons again

Comment: Different how? `JFXToggleButton` appears to be a subclass of the regular `ToggleButton`, so you should just be able to use it the exact same way.

Comment: they looked very different, ToggleButton is just like regular button whereas JFXToggleButton seemed very different than a regular button